# Azure Function App python - async execution of stored procedure on PostgreSQL (psycopg2)

Tags: python, azure-functions, psycopg2

I am trying to write Python Azure Function App, that will execute async some PostgreSQL stored procedure. I do not need to wait in Function itself for the results of the execution. I would like just to trigger the execution and end the Function App. The library that I'm using to connect to PostgreSQL is psycopg2.
Is this possible with this library?
If yes then how?

Comment: Even if you used library like `aiopg`, the calling program has to be running when the SP completes. So, you cannot use it as fire and forget kind of manner from within Azure function. Instead you should have some extension in PG that executes a `job on the server`, and takes the parameters for the SP. Then your function can kick off that 'job', and immediately end the execution.

Comment: @Tcheslav Tcheslav have u found a solution?

Comment: I did workaround. I have executed psql installed on vm via ssh in background.